# Creating a model with many-to-many relations and coefficient

Tags: django

Let's imagine that we want to create a database of food recipes. To do this, we create a class in models (for example, class DishModel) and set a ManyToManyField relationship with the class of ingredients (class IngredientsModel). But here the question arises... This way we will determine only the list of ingredients, but not the quantity that needs to be added to the final dish.

The question is, what is the best way to define the class DishModel field to store the ingredient + quantity combination?

PS I read about MultiValueField, but it is for forms. Is there an analogue for models?

PSS Creating the appropriate field in the class IngredientsModel is not logically correct, because the quantity of an ingredient is information about the dish, not the ingredient. The ingredients can be used in many dishes.

Answer (score 2):

You can define these in a [**`through=`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredient, through='DishIngredient', related_name='dishes'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class DishIngredient(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('dish', 'ingredient'), name='ingredient_once_per_dish'
            )
        ]
```

we can then for a dish for example get the `DishIngredient`s and thus print the ingredients with their quantity:

```
dish = # some_dish

for ingredient in dish.dishingredient_set.select_related('ingredient'):
    print(f'{ingredient.quantity} {ingredient.ingredient}')
```

Comment: Willem, thanks a lot! I got it and read the docs, but I'm missing a small thing...
Patrameter *name* in models.UniqueConstraint, what is it about and what is it for?

If I got it correctly UniqueConstraint set up a rule of the uniqueness for some field (or processing of a field(s)). And create a name for the rule... Why?

Comment: @Tim-Tam: that is the one they use in the database, so that the constraint can later be modified, removed, etc.